Multiple Task Manager columns are grayed out in Windows 11
After installing Windows 11 from scratch many columns in Task Manager columns are grayed out, including Disk, Network, GPU, GPU engine, Power usage and Power usage trend. All the drivers are installed, and I've not used any optimizers or tweakers, I've not touched registry or Group Policy.
This is also discussed here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disk-and-network-columns-are-missing-in-task/46f8cc7e-c9a8-46b2-9f37-980874da05c8
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/processs-gpu-utilization-is-missing-in-task/e5c54aa5-f1a6-470d-9164-c504f36dd5d8



No amount of Googling has produced any results.
What has worked however is removing the user account files and logging in again. Under some circumstances Windows 11 populates the user account with broken registry entries.
Alternatively, you can simply create a new user account and use it instead.
